# Cannot connect with conda install

Tags: python, installation, anaconda

I'm currently having trouble with conda install.

I could download anaconda without any issues and can use the currently installed packages, but I would like to install packages that do not come standard with anaconda (such as rdkit). However, I run into issues when I try the following code in the command line.

C:\Users\My_Username>conda install rdkit

When I input the above into the command line, I see the following

fetching package metadata...
could not connect to https://conda.binstar.org/conda-forge/win-64/
could not connect to https://conda.anaconda.org/conda-forge/win-64/

I thought I might be working behind a proxy since I'm on a work computer, but when I check my browser I am not working behind a proxy.

Can someone please help me resolve this issue? I'm on windows 7 working in conda version 3.7.1. I cannot update conda using conda update conda because I run into the same "could not connect" issues. I also cannot search packages for the same reasons.

Comment: it might be because the actual repo is down?

Comment: Perhaps? Not sure how I would check this. I've had this problem for over a week.

Comment: Did you try to install from the rdkit channel? conda install -c https://conda.anaconda.org/rdkit rdkit

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue recently, and I was able to get around it by using `conda install -k mypackage`.  The `-k` means that conda won't verify the certificate in the SSL connection.  (I believe that my workplace is using virus-scanning / "threat protection" software that prevents strict verification of certificates, or at least interferes in some way.)